# What's the best way to debug a crash that's tableview related for adhoc/release build?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a crash that's happening in user's build that I cannot reproduce on my end.  What's the best way to go about finding out what causes this?

Specifically, if I want to NSLog or catch the exception, where should I do this (based on the crash log below)? NOTE: The tableview uses custom UITableViewCell.

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) 
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000 
Crashed Thread: 0 

Last Exception Backtrace: 
0 CoreFoundation 0x361db88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163 
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x37430259 objc_exception_throw + 33 
2 CoreFoundation 0x361db789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1 
3 Foundation 0x375fd3a3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 91 
4 UIKit 0x30eb1163 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 739 
5 UIKit 0x30eb0181 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1077 
6 UIKit 0x30eaf90b -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207 
7 UIKit 0x30e540df -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 183 
8 CoreFoundation 0x3613a1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43 
9 QuartzCore 0x37f26aa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 217 
10 QuartzCore 0x37f266bd CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 217 
11 QuartzCore 0x37f2a843 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 227 
12 QuartzCore 0x37f2a57f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315 
13 QuartzCore 0x37f224b9 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 57 
14 CoreFoundation 0x361afb1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19 
15 CoreFoundation 0x361add57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 259 
16 CoreFoundation 0x361ae0b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 761 
17 CoreFoundation 0x361314a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301 
18 CoreFoundation 0x3613136d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 
19 GraphicsServices 0x324f1439 GSEventRunModal + 137 
20 UIKit 0x30e7ee7d UIApplicationMain + 1081
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's the code involving table row/section insertion/deletion/move. It's a real pain to debug these without seeing error messages in the console. I would just focus on the places where I dynamically modify the table view.